# Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I don't know a lot about cmake, I'm trying to build a client using cmake and Qt. Getting the following error:

> CMake Error at alethzero/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):   By not
>   providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
>   has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
>   "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
> qt5widgets-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

As far as I understand, I need to add the QT path to CMake. How do I do it? I have Qt installed in /home/user/Programs. All the explanations I find are "just do this or that". I need the exact Terminal commands so I can just learn how to do it in the future.

Thanks!

UPDATE: `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/Programs` did not help me.

Comment: Also, if you don't have QT on Ubuntu you can install it using `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

Answer (score 21):

Well, here you have a solution for Windows: [How to find qt5 CMake module on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639781/how-to-find-qt5-cmake-module-on-windows)

```
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\Qt5.0.1\\5.0.1\\msvc2010\\")
```

For your environment, I think you will have to change the path where Qt is located...

Maybe this will help you:
https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/issues/205

Comment: it worked really good answer. why did they gave you a minus i don't get it. the answer didn't work. but yours did

Comment: Maybe you could give +1 :) ... Well I think is because this answer is only for Windows, and it appears that the OP is using Linux. At the end the only change will be the path...

Comment: for unknown reasons with cmake 3.10. It has not worked, I had to export the variable in shell.

Answer (score 16):

This is documented:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

```
The easiest way to use CMake is to set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
environment variable to the install prefix of Qt 5
```

Do this

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/Programs/<other_stuff>
```

where  references the compiler etc, so that this complete path is valid:

```
/home/user/Programs/<other_stuff>/bin/qmake*
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done that before and I'm still getting the same result. Maybe I should re-install QT from source. (I installed it with their .run package).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to give a correct answer. You don't need to compile Qt from source.

Comment: This is the best answer I think.  I set `CCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2013_6` and it worked for me. Note that in QtCreator I did not need to do this. Apparently, QtCreator already takes care of this but if I use cmake independent of QtCreator I have to do this.

Answer (score 7):

I needed this on my macOS after Qt installation with `brew install qt5`:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0/
```

Comment: This was the solution for me running Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 3):

For ubuntu:
`cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ryan/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64 ..`

`/home/ryan/Qt/` is the Qt installation root path

Answer (score 2):

at an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS desktop the solution was

```
cmake .. -DMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
```