# Ros catkin_make fail with Qt

Tags: ros

I'm getting this error when I catkin_make my workspace:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/ankilp/test_ws/devel/lib/lidar_depth/lidar_depth
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Widgets
```

This is my CMakeList file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(lidar_depth)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  genmsg
)

find_package( PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)

include(${QT_USE_FILE})

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)

catkin_package(

)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/LidarDepth.cpp src/Projection_matrices.hpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
   ${QT_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I don't explicitly use anything related to Qt. I installed Qt5 separately but the problem persists. Is there a separate process to link Qt to my system?

Comment: Are you using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using at least ROS Kinetic (based on the comment where you add compile options). Most things in Kinetic [depend on Qt5 instead of Qt4](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration#Qt4.2BAC8-Qt5_Guidelines). Try making the following changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

Replace this line

```
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui REQUIRED)
```

with these lines

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets REQUIRED)
set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
```

If this doesn't work for you, leave a comment as I have a working `CMakeLists.txt` file for Qt5 in Kinetic and can probably determine what else needs changed, but I think that is the minimal change to make.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Qt seperately, you have to tell CMAKE where it can find you installation. This can be done by specifying the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH inside the CMakeLists.txt file or in the terminal before executing cmake ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215900/add-the-installation-prefix-of-qt5widgets-to-cmake-prefix-path)). E.g.:

```
$ export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/location/to/you/installation
```