# Combining Qt 5.4.1 with vtk 6.2.0 (using CMake GUI 3.2.1) on Windows

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, vtk, cmake-gui

I know almost nothing about CMake. What I'm trying to do is to use VTK with Qt. Unfortunately, I'm stuck at the CMake part. For some reason, when I press "configure", I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

---

What I've done :

1. Install Qt 5.4.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, 722 MB)

   Install vtk 6.2.0

   Install CMake 3.2.1
2. Extract vtk, and using the CMake GUI, set up the source code path and binary build.
3. Set up several environment variables:

   ```
   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = E:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64
   QTDIR = E:\Qt\Qt5.4.1
   Path = E:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;E:\vtk\bin\bin\Debug;E:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin
   ```
4. In CMake GUI, check the following options :

   `VTK_Group_Qt` = true

   `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` = true

   `VTK_QT_VERSION` = 5

   `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` = E:/Qt/Qt5.4.1/5.4/msvc2013_64/bin/qmake.exe
5. Press configure.
6. Get the above error.

What should I do to not get any error?

Thank you!

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639781/how-to-find-qt5-cmake-module-on-windows

Comment: I'm a moron, I thought the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH had to be an environment variable... thank you!

Comment: :) Don't worry, that was quick to solve!