# Install VTK 6.2.0 with Qt 5.4 using CMake-GUI 3.2.2

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk

This is the first time I try to use Vtk libraries but I can not find a tutorial that can help me with the qt integration. I tried several tutorials but when I try to write some code, qt can not find vtk libraries.
I followed this post but something doesn't work correctly: [Combining Qt 5.4.1 with vtk 6.2.0 (using CMake GUI 3.2.1) on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905655/combining-qt-5-4-1-with-vtk-6-2-0-using-cmake-gui-3-2-1-on-windows) 
Can someone explain me the correct procedure? I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, VTK 6.2.0, QT 5.4 and CMake-GUI 3.2.2.
Thanks to all who respond!

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the vtk solution in debug or release? In the example you linked (it was me), I did it in debug, so it will only work in debug (until I build it in release)

also, maybe it's your cMakeList the problem. Did you manage to launch the project EasyView from the vtk solution?

Finally, the tutorial I followed was this one : http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/QtSetup

The only thing I had to modify, was to change the qt version to 5, add another entry cmake_prefix and set up several environment variables.

Comment: How can I build the vtk solution in debug or release? Sorry but I'm not an expert of cmake :(

Comment: it's not in cmake, it's in visual studio that you do this

Answer (score 0):

Try to create Qt project with cmake instead of qmake like is described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)

For a first step try to write just hello world in Qt and try to create cmake for it..

Then you just add the VTK find functions and use those to add vtk support to your qt cmake project. Maybe its something like this (never used vtk):

```
FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})
```

Then you should be able to use Qt and vtk in same project..