# Unresolve external symbol error when using QVTKWidget(VTK 6.2.0) in QT(5.4.2)

Tags: qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

My working environment is:

1. Win 7 64bit
2. Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
3. VTK 6.2.0
4. QT 5.4.2 VS2013 64bit opengl

---

My VTK 6.2.0 was built from CMAKE and has followed all the setup mentioned in

[Install VTK 6.2.0 with Qt 5.4 using CMake-GUI 3.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252858/install-vtk-6-2-0-with-qt-5-4-using-cmake-gui-3-2-2)

[Combining Qt 5.4.1 with vtk 6.2.0 (using CMake GUI 3.2.1) on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905655/combining-qt-5-4-1-with-vtk-6-2-0-using-cmake-gui-3-2-1-on-windows)

with no mistake or error.

After that I used Visual Studio 2013 build the VTK.sln solution with Debug mode successfully.

Then I copied "QVTKWidgetPlugin.lib" and "QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll" to "lib" and "bin" folder of QT 5.4.2, identically.

I also copied "QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll" to "C:QT's path/plugin/designer"

I created a new project in QT Creator 3.4.1 and drag a Widget to the mainwindow, right click and choose "promote to" to add QVTKWidget in it.

[image: Promote to]

and I added these two lines of code to my .pro file

INCLUDEPATH += C:/VTK-6.2.0/include \
LIBS += -LC:/VTK-6.2.0/A_Build/lib/Debug \

I rebuilt it, and errors popped up

[image: Errors]

Did I miss something during the process?

Comment: So far the only reason I can think of is that VTK 6.2.0 is not stable in QT 5.4.2. I would like to know is there anyone successfully build the environment I list above?

Comment: I'll try building VTK 5.10.1 in QT 4.8.6 on another computer with the same procedure, it seems like a stable combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work in the examples provided on visual studio?

Two things come to my mind since I had the same problem with qtCreator

1. Copying the .dll and .lib in /tools/Qtcreator/bin/plugins/designer and /tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/plugins      seemed to solve some problem where my qvtkwidget was not recognized in qtcreator.
2. Did you run qmake in qtcreator? It seems to be a common mistake with new qt users.

EDIT : 3. Did you try adding all the necessary libs one by one? When I removed all the "qt" and "qvtk" libs of my makefile, I would have exactly the same error as you.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VTK\\include\\vtk-6.2\\"

LIBS += -LC:\vtk\bin\lib\Release

LIBS += -lvtkCommonCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonExecutionModel-6.2
LIBS += -lvtksys-6.2
LIBS += -lQVTKWidgetPlugin                 # QT RELATED
LIBS += -lvtkChartsCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkViewsQt-6.2                   # QT Related
LIBS += -lvtkInteractionWidgets-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkInfovisCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingOpenGL-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtklibxml2-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkDICOMParser-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkpng-6.2
LIBS += -lvtktiff-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkzlib-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkjpeg-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkalglib-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkexpat-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkverdict-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkmetaio-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkNetCDF-6.2
LIBS += -lvtksqlite-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkexoIIc-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkftgl-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkfreetype-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersSources-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkGUISupportQt-6.2             #QT related

LIBS += -lvtkalglib-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkChartsCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonColor-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonDataModel-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonExecutionModel-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonMath-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonMisc-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonSystem-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkCommonTransforms-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkDICOMParser-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkDomainsChemistry-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkexoIIc-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkexpat-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersAMR-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersExtraction-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersFlowPaths-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersGeneral-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersGeneric-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersGeometry-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersHybrid-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersHyperTree-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersImaging-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersModeling-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersParallel-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersParallelImaging-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersProgrammable-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersSelection-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersSMP-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersSources-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersStatistics-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersTexture-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkFiltersVerdict-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkfreetype-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkftgl-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkGeovisCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkgl2ps-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkGUISupportQt-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkGUISupportQtOpenGL-6.2           #qt related
LIBS += -lvtkGUISupportQtSQL-6.2              #qt related
LIBS += -lvtkGUISupportQtWebkit-6.2           #qt related
LIBS += -lvtkhdf5_hl-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkhdf5-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingColor-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingFourier-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingGeneral-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingHybrid-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingMath-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingMorphological-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingSources-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingStatistics-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkImagingStencil-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkInfovisCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkInfovisLayout-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkInteractionImage-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkInteractionStyle-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkInteractionWidgets-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOAMR-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOEnSight-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOExodus-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOExport-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOGeometry-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOImage-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOImport-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOInfovis-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOLegacy-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOLSDyna-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOMINC-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOMovie-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIONetCDF-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOParallel-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOPLY-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOSQL-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOVideo-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOXML-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkIOXMLParser-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkjpeg-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkjsoncpp-6.2
LIBS += -lvtklibxml2-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkLocalExample-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkmetaio-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkNetCDF_cxx-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkNetCDF-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkoggtheora-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkParallelCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkpng-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkproj4-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingAnnotation-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingContext2D-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingFreeType-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingGL2PS-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingImage-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingLabel-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingLIC-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingLOD-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingOpenGL-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingQt-6.2                   #qt related
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingVolume-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingVolumeAMR-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL-6.2
LIBS += -lvtksqlite-6.2
LIBS += -lvtksys-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkTestingRendering-6.2
LIBS += -lvtktiff-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkverdict-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkViewsContext2D-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkViewsCore-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkViewsGeovis-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkViewsInfovis-6.2
LIBS += -lvtkViewsQt-6.2                   #QT Related
LIBS += -lvtkzlib-6.2
```

Comment: I already done all the things you mentioned, still the problem exists.

Comment: Added an edit to the answer. If you have other link error not reated to qt, simply remove the problematic lib, or reconfigure your cmake to add these libraries

Comment: I almost realized the same thing as I saw your new edit and VTK's examples of QVTKWidget. You're right!!