# Building vtk with QT5 windows 8

Tags: windows, cmake, qt5, vtk

I'm facing a rather weird error. I can see on the wiki that we can build vtk with support for qt5. However, when trying to do so and first configuring with cmake I get the following output:

CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1326 (message): 
  Found unsuitable Qt version "5.4.2" from 
  C:/Qt/5.4/msvc2012_opengl/bin/qmake.exe, this code requires Qt 4.x 
Call Stack (most recent call first): 
  GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:71 (find_package)

I have followed previous posts on SO like: [How to find qt5 CMake module on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639781/how-to-find-qt5-cmake-module-on-windows)
or
[cmake does not find qt 5.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722329/cmake-does-not-find-qt-5-1-1) but they do not solve my problem so far.

I have tried to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to C:/Qt/5.4/msvc2012_opengl/ and QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE to C:/Qt/5.4/msvc2012_opengl/bin/qmake.exe

And yet it doesn't work. Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you do step 3 and 4 here? : [Combining Qt 5.4.1 with vtk 6.2.0 (using CMake GUI 3.2.1) on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905655/combining-qt-5-4-1-with-vtk-6-2-0-using-cmake-gui-3-2-1-on-windows)

I'm guessing you didn't change VTK_QT_VERSION to 5

Comment: Indeed. Or to be precise I did, it failed and then i just relaunched everything from scratch and now it works :). Thanks a lot :)